# how to import owl carousel in Vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, owl-carousel

hi i created a vue cli 3 project and i'm trying to import owl carousel 2, but it fails.

this is my main.js:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var $ = global.jQuery;
window.$ = $;

import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap";
```

but i get this error on console:

```
owl.carousel.js?555f:1718 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at eval (owl.carousel.js?555f:1718)
    at eval (owl.carousel.js?555f:1755)
    at Object../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js (app.js:1829)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at Module.eval (main.js:14)
    at eval (main.js:39)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:2249)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
```

Comment: The general rule with combining jQuery with Vue is: "don't do it". Are there legacy requirements forcing you to use jQuery? Else I would suggest using https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel or https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper

Comment: @Imre_G i'm converting my html template in to vue app. and i need jquery.jquery is working, but owl doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

by writing this code:

```
let owl_carousel = require('owl.carousel');
window.fn = owl_carousel;
```

it fiexd :)